# Как изменить правильно .click на .on?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Такой вопрос, нужно изменить .click на .on, но если это сделать код теряет свою свойственность, подскажите как это сделать правильно на примере?

```
$(document).on("scroll", onScroll);

$("a[href^=#]").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $(document).off("scroll");
    $(menu_selector + " a.active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    var hash = $(this).attr("href");
    var target = $(hash);

    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top
    }, 900, function(){
        $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
    });

});
```

Comment: что значит _код теряет свою свойственность_?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Можно вот так:

```
$(document).on("scroll", onScroll);

$(document).on('click', 'a[href^=#]', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $(document).off("scroll");
    $(menu_selector + " a.active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    var hash = $(this).attr("href");
    var target = $(hash);

    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top
    }, 900, function(){
        $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
    });

});
```

Comment: подскажите еще пожалуйста, этот код не работает с jquery 3+, можно как то решить эту проблему?

Comment: @vladislav_zp, если у вас атрибут в кавычках, то нужна запускать с `a[href^="#"]`